# mass of the solid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the mass of the solid bounded by the $xy$-plane, $yz$-plane, $xz$-plane, and the plane $x/2+y/3+z/6=1$ if the density of the solid is given by $\delta(x,y,z)=x+4y$.

Cannot set the limits and the integral function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mass is the triple integral of the density function:

Int(x = 0 to 2)Int(y = 0 to 3 - 1.5x)Int(z = 0 to 6 - 3x - 2y)(x + 4y) dzdydx. You can

now integrate it with z first, then y, and then x.

Comment: thanks I really appreciate that!

Comment: you are welcome.